# How is Result-Set Query Scale done in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: nosql, google-cloud-datastore, document-database

It is mentioned that making queries in Google Cloud Datastore is as expensive, with regards to time, as the number of results, which means that, for example, the time it takes to run any query would be proportional only to the number of matching results.

Can anyone give some explanation about how is it done in GCD or NoSQL Documented database?

I know there is a possible that you can implement the distributed system and run queries in parallel. But it is mentioned that the Datastore uses indexing to accomplish this, how would the indexing be in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Queries in Cloud Datastore must use an index.  There are no queries that scan the entire database.

On how indexes work in general, the indexes in Cloud Datastore all ordered indexes, and for each indexed property there is a write to a separate index table which is used to answer a query.  You can find details at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes .